# UITableView issue regarding tick mark and reloading cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview

I have a tableview with 5 sections and variable number of rows in each section with a custom cell (for check and uncheck images on a cell). When I select a row in first section, tableview also selects any one of the row in the last section.

And when I scroll up and down, the checked rows are getting shifted randomly with in the sections.

The issue is that it's not there when I remove one section in the tableview. I.e even number of sections.

Can anyone help me?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellID";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (CustomCell *) [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID]autorelease];
    }
```

That is the code that I used.

I'm sure somewhere I did a mistake. But, I'm not able to find it.

Comment: I think there's something wrong when reuse cells. Would you please post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I have a strong feeling the problem lies there

Answer (score 0):

this is because of reusing of cells in the table, read more about table reusing methodology.
To go in detail the changes made to a cell will be copied to others since the cells are reused to viewable cells.

Answer (score 0):

We will need to see some code to properly diagnose the problem, specifically the implementation of `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`.

Are you correctly reusing the cells as specified in [apples docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) i.e.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyAwsomeCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```